# Using wso2 application server 5.0.1, can I use cxf 2.7.2 in my webapp?

Tags: classloader, wso2

My webapp includes CXF 2.7.2 jar files. When deployed to WSO2 application server the classes that are loaded are from the earlier version of CXF deployed in repository/components/plugins/ not from the libs included in the war.

How do I get the webapp to use the libraries that are included in the WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to know the same. In the mean time I decided to deploy my application as a Web Application rather than a JAX-RS Web Service, and have included the CXF 2.7.2 library and related dependencies with the webapp (in WEB-INF/lib). This worked for me, but I'm using it as a temporary solution until we get a better answer to the above.